# symfony2 routing issues

Tags: php, symfony

I am getting the following error:

```
The autoloader expected class "Acme\HelloBundle\Controller\HelloController" to be defined in file "/var/www/Symfony/app/../src/Acme/HelloBundle/Controller/HelloController.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.
```

The controller code I have is actually:

```
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class HelloController
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>Hello '.$name.'!</body></html>');
    }
}
```

any idea why this is?

Comment: Everything looks ok. However, all my controllers extend `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;`, but I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it

Comment: Probably typo in filename or in folder name

Comment: which filename and folder? I don't see any typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller should extend `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`

```
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Controller;


class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return new Response('<html><body>Hello '.$name.'!</body></html>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`<?php namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Controller;
....`

Just add the "*LESS_THAN*"?php tag at the beginning. Try if works.

Comment: Seems very common (hit me too);  same thing 
[Symfony Database Tutorial code error][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482320/symfony-database-tutorial-code-error/7483225], [symfony2 Unable to find controller][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662876/symfony2-unable-to-find-controller?rq=1], and probably others.